# how do I update the Android options menu so the backward compatible actionbar updates?

Tags: android, android-fragments, backwards-compatibility, android-actionbar, android-optionsmenu

I have made a android app with the "new" actionbar and fragments api but I wanted it to work on phones below android 3.0... so I tested this one:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html

and using the compatibility pack from google...

but I now realize that the setHasOptionsMenu(true) wont work...

to sum it up, I want to update the actionbar menu from runtime... I have tried updating the options menu but havent found a way that works... so please help me :)

Edit: One thing I have realized is that it isnt the setHasOptionsMenu(true) function that wont work, its the actionbar that doesnt update when I try to update the optionsmenu...